# Can't find file uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to create a directory where I can store files to download/link to...for example, I have a CSV file with data I need to use on another site.

I created a folder in `app/assets/` named `files/site1content`. If I go to `http://mysite.com/assets/files/site1content/filename.txt`, I get a "could not find mysite.com".

Does something need to be configured in the routes?

Answer (score 0):

The public folder is aimed for public access, put your files in `public/files/site1content` folder.

Comment: Would the link be something like `www.mysite.com/public/files/site1content`?

Comment: It will be www.mysite.com/files/site1content